# MYSQL multiple grouping with join

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT 
  p.product,
  q.format,
  p.title
FROM 
  product p
  JOIN info q  ON p.product = q.product
WHERE p.user='$user'
GROUP BY p.product,q.format
```

I want to first group by 'product' from the product table but the also by format on the info table.

This is to not show duplicates of format and product. At the moment only the grouping by product is working.

Table - products

```
product    | title    
0            one            
1            two        
1            two - a    
2            three
```

Table - product_details

```
product    | title    | format |
0            one         home      
1            two         home     
1            two - a     home      
2            three       work
```

So for this example I want a list like:

```
 product    | title    |  format
 0             one        home
 2            three       work
```

Instead of:

```
 product    | title    |  format
 0             one        home 
 1             two        home    
 2            three       work
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` is not appropriate here since you have no aggregate functions (`COUNT(),SUM(),MAX(),`etc) Do you intend to _order_ on those two columns?  Please post a sample of your data and a sample of what you expect the result to be.

Comment: Just noticed the _this is not to show duplicates_. Instead of `GROUP BY`, do `SELECT DISTINCT p.product, q.format`

Comment: If this is all your code, as we will assume unless you post more code, you can just add `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT`.

Comment: I have made a edit and added p.title, there are other fields to retrieve that should not be covered by DISTINCT, I don't know how to use DISTINCT and apply it to only specific fields

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies over the entire row, not to any specific column. If it does not give you the result you expect, you need to post the expected result as suggested earlier.

Comment: Well it's ok to display results that have the same title but not ok to display results that have the same format or product value, that's all there is to it.

Comment: And what I'm saying to you is _that's exactly what DISTINCT does_, as you describe. If you need a different result set than what `DISTINCT` provides, post it.

Comment: If if add DISTINCT after select it will eliminate rows with the same p.title and I don't want it to do that.

Comment: I just tried adding DISTINCT and it didn't even eliminate rows with the same product value.

Comment: I can't help you further if you continue to ignore pleas to post an actual sample of rows from your tables and an actual sample of the rows you would expect your query to return. Notice you have no answers to what would otherwise be a simple SQL question - you are not providing enough information.  You misunderstand both the purpose of `GROUP BY` (value aggregation) and `DISTINCT` (unique result deduplication) so we _must_ see a data sample and a result sample typed out above to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added examples, every answer like this I find online suggests using GROUP BY

Comment: This is the second question in a row you've asked me to post more info then not given in an answer, I honestly don't know what to make of that.

Comment: Looking at your examples above, what I ascertain is that you only want to return those products which have exactly 1 value for `products.title`, and not those which have multiple `products.title` for the same `product.product`. Is that correct?

Comment: @user1209203 If you don't @ me in the comments, I don't get notified of updates or changes. I just happened to look back through my comment history today to see whatever became of this.

Answer (score 0):

After your table structures were posted, I can see what your intent is, I believe.  It looks like you are attempting to limit your output result set to those values for `product.product` which are never repeated. That is, values for `product.product` which have exactly one `product.title`.

For that, you can use a `GROUP BY` aggregation to return only those with `COUNT(*) = 1` after the group is applied.

In this case, since you only expect one row back per `product.product` anyway, you can do the aggregation at the top level, not requiring a subquery. If you had joined in other tables, and ended up getting multiple rows back per `product` due to other one-to-many relationships, you would need to use the subquery method instead (to be portable anyway - MySQL would still probably allow this)

```
SELECT 
  p.product,
  q.format,
  p.title
FROM 
  products p
  JOIN product_details q ON p.product = q.product
GROUP BY
  p.product,
  q.format,
  p.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72eda/6

If you did expect multiple rows back per `p.product`, such as if you joined in additional one-to-many related tables, an efficient way to handle that is to perform a `JOIN` against a subquery that imposes that limit in the `HAVING` clause. Those which don't meet the `HAVING` condition won't be returned in the subquery and therefore get discarded by the `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
  p.product,
  q.format,
  p.title
FROM 
  products p
  INNER JOIN product_details q ON p.product = q.product
  /* Subquery returns only product values having exactly 1 row */
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT product
    FROM products
    GROUP BY product
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  ) pcount ON p.product = pcount.product
WHERE p.user = '$user'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72eda/2